# Evaluate limit $x^2$ and $\sqrt{1+2/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+1-2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}\right)$$

I tried substitution $t = 1/x$ but did not help. L'Hospital did not work either.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you try a conjugate?  (Or, perhaps, two conjugates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the square root in series in $t\rightarrow0$:

$$\sqrt{1+t} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}t - \frac{1}{8}t^2 + o(t^2)$$

where $o(t^2)$ are insignificant terms that tend to 0.

In your case $\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 0$ and also $\frac{2}{x} \rightarrow 0$ so
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+1-2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}\right) = $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \left( \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{x} - \frac{1}{8}\frac{4}{x^2} + o(x^{-2}) \right) + 1 - 2\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{x^2} + o(x^{-2}) \right) \right) = $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \left( -\frac{1}{4x^2} + o(x^{-2})\right) = -\frac{1}{4}$$

The idea of this method is that you are trying to construct in a point $x_0$ the original function using only simple polynomials.

The [same idea](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LogTay.svg) is used when you expand in Taylor series.

Comment: Although you don't need all those terms! :)

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work? I know the solution should be $-\frac 14$. Either I get $\infty$ or $0$...

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with l'Hôpital: do the substitution $t=1/x$.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+1-2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}\right)&=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+t}}{t^2}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2t}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}}{2t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2t}\sqrt{1+t}}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{1+2t}}{2t}
\end{align}
This should be easier. Hint: you can disregard the first factor, because it has limit $1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as:
$$ \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2z}-2\sqrt{1+z}}{z^2}. $$
Since for any $z>0$:
$$ 1+\frac{z}{2}-\sqrt{1+z}=\frac{\frac{z^2}{4}}{1+\frac{z}{2}+\sqrt{1+z}}\in\left(\frac{z^2}{8},\frac{z^2}{8+2z}\right), $$
we have:

$$ \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2z}-2\sqrt{1+z}}{z^2} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{-\frac{z^2}{2}+2\frac{z^2}{8}}{z^2}=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{4}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
l&=\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+1-2\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}\right)\\
&=
\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x-2\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)\\
&=
\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x-2\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)\times \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+2\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+2\sqrt{x^2+x}}\\
&=-2\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+2\sqrt{x^2+x}}\\
&=-2\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+2\sqrt{x^2+x}}\times \frac{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\\
&=-2\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x+2\sqrt{x^2+x}}\times \frac{1}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\\
&=-2\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac2x}+1+2\sqrt{1+\frac1x}}\times \frac{1}{1+\frac1x+\sqrt{1+\frac2x}}\\
&=-2\times \frac14 \times \frac12\\
&=-\frac14
\end{align}